# OwnCloud: Permission denied for www-data on mounted drive

Tags: server, mount, permissions, apache2, fstab

I am experiencing problem with setting up correct permissions for www-data user and group on external FAT drive. I want to this drive to be accessed by ownCloud and therefore I have set up following `/etc/fstab` in following way:

```
UUID=xxxx-xxx      /media/pi/EOS_DIGITAL   vfat    umask=777,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,utf8,nofail 0       0
```

After mounting and running `sudo ls -la /media/pi/EOS_DIGITAL` I receive following output:

```
total 100
drwxrwx---  4 www-data www-data 32768 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-x---+ 4 root     root      4096 Nov 18 21:56 ..
drwxrwx---  5 www-data www-data 32768 Jul 28 18:23 DCIM
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data 32768 Jul 28 18:23 MISC
```

However when trying to access this folder with www-data I am receiving **Permission denied** message. I am not able to setup ownCloud as well:

```
Can't create or write into the data directory /media/pi/EOS_DIGITAL
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This is about Raspbian and as such off-topic here.

Comment: @CelticWarrior please could you tell me how you know that?

Comment: @Zanna Because of the other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/851223/owncloud-change-folder-for-specific-user . The user is already aware of the off-topic.

Comment: @Zanna: I think we should keep it open. The situation would have been identical in Ubuntu (it's about POSIX access permissions after all) and it has a worthwhile accepted answer. As a rule of thumb we shouldn't close questions with good accepted answers unless they blatantly violate the rules (terdon told me that recently but I can't a reference to it atm).

Comment: @DavidFoerster oh hmm well I definitely agree with that, my general policy is to only VTC as dupe if I see the post has a valid accepted answer & otherwise leave open. I didn't notice in this case.  Retracted

Comment: @CelticWarrior: The same goes for you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drwxr-x---+ 4 root     root      4096 Nov 18 21:56 ..
```

These are the permissions of the `/media/pi` folder. As you can see the owner is the root user and other users cannot access the files and folders inside it.

You need to set the owner of that folder to www-data

```
chown www-data:www-data /media/pi
```

Comment: but `..` shows the permissions for parent folder (/media/pi in this case)

Comment: You're right! Sorry, my bad! You need to chown the /media/pi folder and not /media/pi/EOS_DIGITAL

Comment: My answer is corrected now.