# OwnCloud: change folder for specific user

Tags: server, permissions, raspberrypi, owncloud-server, owncloud-client

I have just installed OwnCloud on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Jessie Pixel 4.4 on board. I have specified the following folder in `config.php` file:

```
'datadirectory' => '/media/user/ownCloud'
```

The thing is that after createing a new ownCloudUser, OwnCloud authomatically created new /ownCloudUser folder in path specified above. As a result all files are stored under

```
/media/user/ownCloud/ownCloudUser
```

Is it possible to setup OwnCloud in the way that `/media/user/ownCloud` will be root folder for *ownCloudUser*?

Comment: Raspbian is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for specifying, but I don't think problem is OS related

Comment: That's not the point. The point is it isn't supported here (off-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user on owncloud has a private home folder.

The `datadirectory` is where owncloud will store the files for all users. Every user will create a new separate folder.

Two quick guesses as to why you would want to control this is because you either want to share some files or you want to preload the user.

---

If what you're trying to do is share a folder for multiple users, you can do that through owncloud.

If you want to preload the folder with data. Owncloud keeps a record of files on the database. This is possible, but a bit more involved than simply dropping files. You need to use `occ` on the server to run the `files:scan` operation.

The full command would be

```
php occ files:scan
```

You can use `-h` for more information.